# Replace average color pixel with images

Tags: javascript

I need to create a mosaic by replacing the pixel of an image on input with images for each colors. The images will be provided by me for some of the most important colors. Obviously it shall be rounded up to the nearest color, because i can't use a picture for every rgb color.
I found this code that i think it could be a good start but i don't know how replace a tile with an image.

```js
var TILE_WIDTH=10;
var TILE_HEIGHT=10;

document.getElementById("input").onchange = function () {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (e) {
         // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
         document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
     };
      // read the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  };
    
      // first function call to create photomosaic 
  function photomosaic(image) {

      // Dimensions of each tile
      var tileWidth = TILE_WIDTH;
      var tileHeight = TILE_HEIGHT;

      //creating the canvas for photomosaic
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.height = image.height;
      canvas.width = image.width;

      var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      var pixels = imageData.data;

      // Number of mosaic tiles
      var numTileRows = image.width / tileWidth;
      var numTileCols = image.height / tileHeight;



      //canvas copy of image
      var imageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var imageCanvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
      imageCanvas.height = image.height;
      imageCanvas.width = image.width;
      imageCanvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      

      //function for finding the average color
      function averageColor(row, column) {
          var blockSize = 1, // we can set how many pixels to skip

              data, width, height,
              i = -4,
              length,
              rgb = {
                  r: 0,
                  g: 0,
                  b: 0
              },
              count = 0;          

          try {
              data = imageCanvasContext.getImageData(column * TILE_WIDTH, row * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH);
          } catch (e) {
              alert('Not happening this time!');
              return rgb;
          }

          length = data.data.length;

          while ((i += blockSize * 4) < length) {
              ++count; //
              rgb.r += data.data[i];
              rgb.g += data.data[i + 1];
              rgb.b += data.data[i + 2];
          }

          // ~~ used to floor values
          rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r / count);
          rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g / count);
          rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b / count);

          return rgb;

      }

      // Loop through each tile
      for (var r = 0; r < numTileRows; r++) {
          for (var c = 0; c < numTileCols; c++) {
              // Set the pixel values for each tile
              var rgb = averageColor(r, c)
              var red = rgb.r;
              var green = rgb.g;
              var blue = rgb.b;

              // Loop through each tile pixel
              for (var tr = 0; tr < tileHeight; tr++) {
                  for (var tc = 0; tc < tileWidth; tc++) {

                      // Calculate the true position of the tile pixel
                      var trueRow = (r * tileHeight) + tr;
                      var trueCol = (c * tileWidth) + tc;

                      // Calculate the position of the current pixel in the array
                      var pos = (trueRow * (imageData.width * 4)) + (trueCol * 4);

                      // Assign the colour to each pixel
                      pixels[pos + 0] = red;
                      pixels[pos + 1] = green;
                      pixels[pos + 2] = blue;
                      pixels[pos + 3] = 255;
                  };
              };
          };
      };

      // Draw image data to the canvas
      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      return canvas;
  }

  function create() {
      var image = document.getElementById('image');
      var canvas = photomosaic(image);
      document.getElementById("output").appendChild(canvas);
  };
```

```css
#output, .container {
 text-align: center;
}
.inputDiv {
 margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
 <img id="image"/>
 <div class="inputDiv">
  <input id="input" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <button onclick="create()">create</button>
 </div>
 <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

[code by gurinderiitr](https://jsfiddle.net/gurinderiitr/sx735L5n/)

Comment: I think it's a more of a *reddit* question than *stackoverflow*

Comment: ... @vsync why?

Comment: This question(s) seem too broad for this website to answer, so nobody would help, unless you will narrow your question down to a very specific thing. In reddit people could help more by providing links to Github projects that might do the thing you want to achieve. Here is a complete different website with different helping goals and it's no a forum like reddit where you can ask complex questions and get a variety of responses.. questions should be narrowed down